# PostgreSQL pattern match on Umlauts

Tags: postgresql, collation

AFAIK all three of the following tests should return true (`t`). They actually work when I append `COLLATE "de_DE"`.

I'm running this on a interactive database-terminal, so not sure the collation is taken into effect? Can I check somehow which collation is in effect and if so change it without modifying the (UTF-8-encoded) data?

```
                                            version                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

=> SELECT 'Ü' ~* 'Ü';
 ?column? 
----------
 t

=> SELECT 'Ü' ~* 'ü';
 ?column? 
----------
 f

=> SELECT 'Ü' ~* '\mÜ';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Alternatively, is there a way to make the pattern match umlaut-insensitive, i.e. have `'Ü' ~*SOMETHINGHERE '\mU'` return `t`? Or should I just append `COLLATE` to all my query calls? Or should I just run the following, will this actually not touch the data, only lookup-behaviour and indices?

```
ALTER TABLE articles ALTER COLUMN title SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(255) COLLATE "de_DE";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default collation used if no collation is specified is the database collation, which you can find with the SQL statements

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

or

```
SELECT current_setting('lc_collate');
```

To use a collation different from the default collation, you either have to explicitly use `COLLATE` in the query to specify the collation to use, or you can use `ALTER TABLE` like you suggested.

That should not rewrite your data, and it will not change any indexes.